# Magento One page checkout not working after upgrade to 1.8

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I have upgraded my site to Magento 1.8. I didnt upgraded the magento using magento downloader. I have used fresh magento 1.8 and moved my skin to this version. Now everything working fine Except the one page checkout page. The checkout progress bar is updating as i complete steps and also the payment is working neither paypal not the creditcard. The place order button does nothing, the site is not directing to payment page.
Here are the couple of steps i have followed with no success
in /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtm 
i have changed this line

```
       <fieldset>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
         </fieldset>
```

to

```
        <fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
         </fieldset>
```

This didnt worked.
And also in
app/design/frontend/default/mobileshoppe/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml

i have changed this line

```
    review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder') ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
```

to

```
       review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
```

Both didnt worked for me. 
Is there any other solutions except this?
Can someone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: pls compare your theme review.xml file with base one will sure help you to get this problem solved. because some change in review.xml in 1.8

Comment: have you disabled cache or clear your cache. ?

Answer (score 2):

Replace the base file the following path
app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml

(or)

Replace the line number 81 in info.phtml by following code:

review = new Review(’getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>’, ‘getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>’, $(’checkout-agreements’));

Comment: i want to save product review directly from  mail everything is done except "Review form form key" can you tell me how can i get a review form key in external file ??

Answer (score 1):

Check the files for the special form key. I had the same problems with the checkout and fixed them that way.

Since Magento 1.8.0.0, the core team has added a form key, which has to be present in order to submit some forms. I guess that your form does not have that form key. It should look like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

You need to compare your template and layout files from the checkout module to the files from the Magento's base/default template and layout.

In the layout files you should search for a block, named `formkey`