# Magento 1.8.1 Checkout - SyntaxError Unexpected Token

Tags: magento, checkout

My website is [Smarticine](https://www.smarticine.com/store/) and I am currently getting this error on the final step of the checkout:

Here is the screenshot from Chrome:
[Error Screenshot](http://demo.rockettheme.com/magento/skitchrokmage/Checkout-20131118-144758.jpg)

1)  The error only occurs when I use the regular One Page Checkout and not Checkout with Multiple Address

2)  I am currently using BluePay CC Module, but it is the same with all other payment options (such as money order).

3)  I have applied the following corrections to my codes, but it does not change: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189273/magento-one-page-checkout-not-working-after-upgrade-to-1-8

4)  I am currently using RocketTheme template but reverting back to default template produces the same error.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps:

Upgrading from 1.7.xx to 1.8.x.x with a custom theme.

You will find that the following don't work:

- One Page Checkout (seems to work but can't proceed to payment)
- Checkout Progress
- Customer Login

Fixes:

OnePageCheckout:

In your theme files - find payment.phtml - add "checkout-payment-method-load" as an ID to the fieldset

In your theme files - find info.phtml - update the `<script>` to be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[ review = new Review('
    <?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '
    <?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements')); // ]]>
</script>
```

Login: add form key to the login as a hidden input: `<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<? echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />`

source: http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento/comments/1ww35x/

Answer (score 1):

Go to {base}/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
go to ~line 36

Preferably add this file to your theme directory instead of modifying Magento files

The line should read

```
<fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

add this id to the fieldset `checkout-payment-method-load`

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

please could you try these steps:

1) activate developer mode (index.php) 

2) enable line: ini_set('display_errors', 1); (index.php)

3) enable logs: Admin Panel > System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled = Yes 

4) try finish checkout again and then check the latest rows in var/log/system.log and var/log/exception.log

if there will be something new please could you attach it here?

Comment: i don't see an exception log.  just a system.log.  this is the copy-paste:

2014-02-03T15:19:04+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: local  in /home/smart/public_html/store/app/code/community/Rockettheme/RokMageLayouts/Model/Update.php on line 78

Comment: line 78:  $adminlocal = $configData['general']['local'];

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to test it on your site but I'm not able get to last checkout step because of no payment methods. Could you tell me if there is some available payment method or if there is some restriction for shipping country vs. payment method at the moment?